# Flex grid alignment

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment

I am trying to display cards (divs) in a container and put them in the center. I use `display:flex` and `justify-content:space-around`. It works great, but in the example I give below, the cards always have to be 4 in a row:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
#container .card {
  flex-basis: 23%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="card">
  Card 1
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 2
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 3
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 4
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 1
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 2
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 3
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 4
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 3
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 4
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I align the last cards to the left and how do I do this the most proper way, also bearing in mind I am showing the card in a `for` loop in `python` or `php`?

`display:grid` is not as cross-browser compatible as `display:flex`, therefore still not a good option for me. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use `flexbox` for this? You can implement the same without using `flexbox`, right? Even `flexbox` is not compatible in browsers like IE. So what I am trying to ask is, if there is any specific reason you used `flexbox`?

Comment: @Abinthaha Flexbox is compatible with IE since version 10 (so 10 and 11). Autoprefixer will add the relevant syntax if these versions are part of your browserslist. IE9 and below aren't supported anymore by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for justify-content in that case. Center the content with equal margins.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
#container .card {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="card">
  Card 1
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 2
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 3
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 4
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 1
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 2
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 3
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 4
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 3
  </div>
  <div class="card">
  Card 4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! What if I want to remove the paddings from the left and right side from the container? so it is like `space-around` ?